# ovirt-node-upgrade command not found

Tags: ovirt

I want to upgrade a oVirt Node offline without using oVirt Engine. I found a pretty good way to do it on the website [documentation](https://www.ovirt.org/develop/projects/node/node-upgrade/) but the command seems not being installed on the oVirt Node 4.1.7. Do I have to install extra packages?

Comment: Why not use the engine?

Comment: This installation failed because the oVirt Engine try to download additional packages to set up the oVirt node. Unfortunately I don't have internet access.

Comment: So download everything and set up a local repo

Comment: I would rather prefer use the `ovirt-node-upgrade` command with the iso than a local repo.

Comment: In my experience you need all the packages for an upgrade either at a local repo or you need internet access for you servers to update. In my setup the servers only can access the mirrors for the updates.